# django: Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. Process finished with exit code 134 SIGABRT

Tags: django

On starting my django project, I am encountering this error:  Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Full trace as follows:

```
Thread 0x00007f9dcdaba700 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576 in readinto
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 140 in handle
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681 in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354 in finish_request
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625 in process_request_thread
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f9dce2bb700 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576 in readinto
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 140 in handle
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681 in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354 in finish_request
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625 in process_request_thread
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f9dceabc700 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576 in readinto
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 140 in handle
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681 in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354 in finish_request
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625 in process_request_thread
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007f9dcf2bd700 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2403 in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2103 in _signature_from_function
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2227 in _signature_from_callable
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2738 in from_callable
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2988 in signature
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/inspect.py", line 12 in getargspec
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 764 in args_check
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 695 in __init__
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 600 in compile_filter
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 903 in create_var
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py", line 177 in translate_token
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py", line 166 in __init__
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 900 in __init__
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 968 in do_if
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 513 in parse
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 312 in do_extends
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 513 in parse
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 230 in compile_nodelist
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 191 in __init__
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 44 in get_template
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 136 in find_template
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 162 in get_template
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 204 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199 in _render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177 in render
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957 in render_annotated
...

Thread 0x00007f9dd06d2700 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 376 in select
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 232 in serve_forever
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174 in run
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 149 in inner_run
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227 in wrapper

Thread 0x00007f9dd519b700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 281 in reloader_thread
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 298 in python_reloader
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 332 in main
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110 in run
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 101 in handle
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330 in execute
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 62 in execute
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283 in run_from_argv
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355 in execute
File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363 in execute_from_command_line
File "/home/grzsqrrl/PycharmProjects/my_proj/my_proj/manage.py", line 22 in <module>

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

The problem here is there is no references to the application code (to start with). I checked similar posts but could not find one similar to my issue,

Any pointers please;

Comment: Maybe post what is going on around line 140 in `File "/home/grzsqrrl/my_proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py"`

Comment: `def handle(self):
      '''Copy of WSGIRequestHandler, but with different ServerHandler'''
        self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
        if len(self.raw_requestline) > 65536:
            self.requestline = ''
            self.request_version = ''
            self.command = ''
            self.send_error(414)
            return
       ...`

Answer (score 1):

Initially upgraded to django==2.0b1 from 1.11.7 and can start seeing application errors instead of django errors. I assumed upgrade was the fix.

However the real issue was in the application itself. There is an infinite loop hidden in the template. home.html includes left_side_menu.html which again inherits from home.html -- circular loop!

Comment: You are right. In my case, I downgraded django from 3.1 to 3.0.5 and issue was fixed.
I guess in my case, the issue was with the foreign key fields that were inherited from abstract model